# ¿como crear un sistema como we transfer?

Tags: web, aplicación-web

me pueden indicar por favor por donde debo empezar para crear una pagina web que funcione de manera similar a we transfer? la idea es saber cuales son los conocimientos necesarios para poder crear un proyecto de este tipo

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy general. Los conocimientos necesarios pueden ser muy variados implicando diversas tecnologías y conocimientos y varios años de estudio y práctica.

Comment: le idea es poder crear una web que permita enviar archivos como se envian por we transfer, es tan complicado?

Comment: Hey juan ordonez, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La pregunta es bastante amplia, por lo que creo deberías replantearlas en preguntas específicas (en base a lo que dice las reglas...)

Respondiendo tu pregunta... HTML+CSS+JS (lo que respecte a UI/UX), AJAX para cargar el contenido, tu server-side puede ser PHP... y una vez subido el documento podés pasarle md5 para tener el hash correspondiente (para pasarlo por GET como ID de archivo para descargarlo o something like that), una dB para guardar el hash correspondiente, datos como nombre, fecha de subida, peso, etc)

Eso en resumen sería... como ya dijimos varias personas, tenes que replantearla porque en realidad la respuesta es un poco mas extensa teniendo en cuenta cuantas cosas debe de abarcar...

Comment: Si la pregunta es bastante amplia ,¿Porque responderla?, tienes suficiente reputación para comentar, tratamos de no responder este tipo de preguntas ya que deben de estar basadas en lo definido en el [help], saludos.

Comment: Así como es amplia, sentí que debía responderle igual, de manera que tenga un pequeño empujón para que pueda empezar a investigar por su cuenta y realizar de a poco el proyecto que quiere encarar, con el fin de seguir viéndolo por Stack pero ya con preguntas puntuales. :)

Comment: Es difícil dar una respuesta para una pregunta "demasiado amplia", incluso esto que agregas como respuesta en  realidad no resuelve lo que desea el OP, en estos casos lo que realizamos es votar para cerrar la pregunta y ayudarlo con alguna opinión agregándola como comentario. Para seguir viéndolo por stackoverflow en español podemos guiarlo a crear preguntas que obtengan buenas respuestas y sea atractivo el sitio como un lugar donde pueda obtener ayuda que además de servirle a el OP le pueda ayudar a otros usuarios.